# Jackson streaming api & WebFlux response body in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm pretty new to Spring Cloud Gateway and Spring WebFlux.

I have a requirement where I need to gather all the IDs of the data elements in the response for logging purposes.

I have done so in a very memory-intensive way, by reading the DataBuffer into a byte array, parsing it and then wrapping it into a DataBuffer and passing it along.

However, this isn't very viable when the responses are big and I am making use of the Jackson Streaming API so it seems silly.

Anyone have any tips on how to achieve this? All the examples I have seen seem to do it in a similar way, by buffering the entire response in memory.

Current version (Groovy):

```
class DataIdResponseHandler extends ServerHttpResponseDecorator {

    final DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory

    DataIdResponseHandler(ServerHttpResponse delegate) {
        super(delegate)
        dataBufferFactory = delegate.bufferFactory()
    }

    @Override
    Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
        Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body

        return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map { dataBuffer ->
            byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()]
            dataBuffer.read(content)

            List<String> dataIds = DataIdParser.parseFromByteArray(content)
            DataIdCollector.add(dataIds)

            return dataBufferFactory.wrap(content)
        })
    }

}
```

Reactive version of the above would method would be:

```
return super.writeWith(fluxBody.doOnNext {  DataBuffer dataBuffer ->
            List<String> dataIds = DataIdParser.parseFromByteArray(dataBuffer.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()).bytes)
            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataIdResponseFilter)
            logger.info(dataIds.toString())
        })
```

Oddly enough, if there's an interaction with the DataBuffer where you access the asInputStream() and you read from that it'll empty the DataBuffer and the actual response will be empty. If you use the toString() method, which obviously also reads from the DataBuffer, the buffer and hence body will still be complete.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your ServerHttpResponseDecorator?

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel added current version in question.

Comment: It would seem like the problem is in the dataBuffer.read method where the actual response is being read into memory. Perhaps a good approach would be to instead of using the read(byte[]) method using the dataBuffer.asInputStream() function where you can then parse the JSON in a streaming manner as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api. If I get some time I'll try to create a working PoC. If you manage to get it working please post your solution here as it's a very interesting topic!

Comment: The problem with using the input stream is that you have to read from the input stream and also capture the output at the same time in order to return it from the method. My parser can take both an inputstream and a byte array, but since I am doing most of the work inside the writeWith in a non-reactive manner I think it's a dead end.

Comment: I had thought about doing something like share the flux, one subscriber parses the body and the other writes the response so to speak. Like in a non-reactive way, have an outputstream wrapper that would sit in the read operation and slowly feed the bytes into the parser while the response is being written. Afterwards it'd have the result of parsing operation.

Comment: Next problem I've run into is that in chunked transferring, I don't get the entire response so it's read in chunks. Which produces another "problem" in regards to using the streaming api since it doens't seem to support that usage pattern.